# How to create directory from URL path separator (forward slash) when that is present in FileName coded %2f or %2F

Tags: powershell, batch-file, url, decode

As I mentioned in Q-title, I have setup a sublime settings auto-syncing process to Github Gist of my choice when I have passed correct Access Token.

Now this process syncs any file that is present inside a folder(s), considering the relative paths, as `DirName%2FFileName.extension` where `DirName` and/or `FileName` may contain singular spaces(`%20`) between words(if >2 words in either).

Now when I download that gist thro' `DownloadZIP` button, it ofcourse downloads the whole gist with multiple files as single zip, which after download can be extracted into it's folder in local system(Windows 10/11 OS).

So, the question finally: When I have downloaded such zip and extracted into folder that contains one/multiple files that have `%2f` or `%2F` in their names, how do I create a directory from those filenames and move those files into those directory thro' a batch file if possible, or a PowerShell command, but runnable from Batch script, and then also rename those files to remove all `DirName%2f` parts from their names ? I know about `mv` and `md` commands but how do I create directory from URL coded character group and do those operations ?

**Note:** `DirName%2f` parts could be occurring in multiples like `DirName1%2fDirName2%2f...` if the file that is being synced from local is inside `mainfolder/subfolders...` relatively.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode("DirName%2FFileName.extension")
```

it gives :

```
DirName/FileName.extension
```

Then you can use the CmdLets with noun "Path" to manage your file names.

```
Get-Command -Noun path
```

If it exists some `/` in place of `\`, Powershel should manage them.

The to work with files and folders is given with CmdLet with noun Item :

```
Get-Command -Noun item
```

For example to create a directory :

```
New-Item -name toto -ItemType Directory
```

Comment: Ok that's great help, can you also add into your answer, how can I create folder(s) based on this decoded string, I mean the only way is thro' `Split-Path` and `ForEach` loop or there's short-way which doesn't involve any could-be heavy looping ? That would make a great head-start for me. Thanks man !! for your effort in informative answer

Comment: @VickyDev, I update my answer this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "#name1=DirName%%2f"
SET "#name2=DirName1%%2fDirName2%%2f"
SET "#name3=DirName1%%2FDirName2%%2F"
SET "#2f=%%2f"
SET "#subs=ABC"

SET #

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ("%#2f%") DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%w IN ("!#name1:%#2f%=%#subs%!") DO ECHO REN "%#name1%" "%%w"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%w IN ("!#name2:%#2f%=%#subs%!") DO ECHO REN "%#name2%" "%%w"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%w IN ("!#name3:%#2f%=%#subs%!") DO ECHO REN "%#name3%" "%%w"
)

ECHO ===================

FOR %%b IN ("%#name1%" "%#name2%" "%#name3%") DO (
 SET "#name=%%~b"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ("%#2f%") DO (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%w IN ("!#name:%#2f%=%#subs%!") DO ECHO REN %%b "%%w"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This demo shows how in batch.